# Generating Signature for Google Work API using node.js

Tags: node.js

I need to generate the Signature  for using Google Map for Work API ( with the Client Id and key as inputs) using node.js. I can see the code in Java,Ruby but not in node.js. can you assist here.

Thanks
Siva.

Answer (score 6):

Google provides a nice [HOWTO](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key) with all technical details. Javascript sample is missing though. The code listed below is an adapted C# version (I put appropriate comments from there).

```
'use strict';

const url = require('url');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const sign = (apiUrl, keyString) => {
    // converting key to bytes will throw an exception, need to replace '-' and '_' characters first.
    const usablePrivateKey = keyString.replace(/[-]/g, '+').replace(/[_]/g, '/');

    const privateKeyBytes = new Buffer(usablePrivateKey, 'base64');
    const uri = url.parse(apiUrl);

    // compute the hash
    const algorithm = crypto.createHmac('sha1', privateKeyBytes);
    const hash = algorithm.update(uri.path).digest('base64');

    // convert the bytes to string and make url-safe by replacing '+' and '/' characters
    const signature = hash.replace(/[+]/g, '-').replace(/[/]/g, '_');

    // add the signature to the existing URI
    return uri.protocol + '//' + uri.host + uri.path + '&signature=' + signature;
};

module.exports = { sign };
```